# How to get the closest samples to time series dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, pytorch

- I have a deep learning time series classification model.
- I want to understand if the model failed to classify, due to missing or incorrupt training inputs.

For simplicity let's say we have a training dataset with 4 sequences, and I want to check which training sequence is the most similar to investigate sample:

[image]

- F1, F2, F3, F4 are the inputs to the model.
- I want to check for F5, which "f" is the clostest ?
  according to the plot, it seems that the red (f1).

When I'm trying to run `KDTree` or `fastdtw`, they give f2 (green).

1. why is it ?
2. which algorithm can I use to get similar samples from the training set ?

full code:

```
import pandas               as pd
import numpy                as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express       as px
import matplotlib.pyplot    as plt

from scipy.spatial          import KDTree

l_colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "black"]
l_title  = ["f1",  "f2",     "f3",    "f4",    "f5"]
arr_data = np.array([[30,  34,  9,  np.nan,  np.nan, np.nan],   # f1
                     [10,  11,  39,    40,    55,    np.nan],      # f2
                     [190, 120, -10, np.nan,  np.nan, np.nan],   # f3
                     [40, 100, -20,  np.nan,  np.nan, np.nan],   # f4
                     [30,  35,  10,   40,     45,      55]])     # f5

def create_plot(data):
    
    for i in range(len(data)):    
        
        time   = np.arange(0, 6)
        values = data[i]
        
        plt.plot(time, values, color=l_colors[i], marker='o', linestyle='-', label=f'{l_title[i]}')
        plt.xlabel('time')
        plt.ylabel('Vol')
        
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    
create_plot(arr_data)

data_no_f5                       = arr_data[:-1]
f5                               = arr_data[-1, :]  
data_no_f5[np.isnan(data_no_f5)] = 0
f5[np.isnan(f5)]                 = 0

tree              = KDTree(data_no_f5)
distance, index   = tree.query(x = f5.reshape(1, -1), 
                               k = 1, # nearest_neighbors, 
                               p = 2) # Euclidean distanc
print(l_title[index[0]])

from fastdtw import fastdtw

distances          = [fastdtw(f5, row)[0] for row in data_no_f5]
closest_row_index = np.argmin(distances)
print(l_title[closest_row_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

your target value has 6 observation and your explanatory variables have missing values. first of all you have to impute missing values then you can use ols regression  and then find maximum R2  among different models.